# conditional operator in where clause select statement does not return data in DB2?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

The below statement does not work for me on DB2 Command Line ? AMOUNT is a column in the table with the Type as DOUBLE. Is my query okay ?

```
DB2 SELECT Name from EMP_TABLE WHERE AMOUNT > 0.00;
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you executing this command?

- In Windows, DB2 in capitals is valid.
- However, in Linux, DB2 is not valid; it should be db2.

Also the 'less than' sign is interpreted as redirection.

The error output of

```
SELECT Name from EMP_TABLE WHERE AMOUNT
```

Will be written in a file called 0.00 in the current directory

Also, the semi-colon is valid in Linux, but not in Windows

Try to execute

```
db2 "SELECT Name from EMP_TABLE WHERE AMOUNT > 0.00"
```

In Linux and Windows it will work.